# Add an "on-link" routing entry

Tags: windows, routing

On Windows 7 I have been using the command `route add` to add routing entries with a gateway. I now want to add a routing entry with no gateway, where the route is directly reachable.

Windows 7 calls such routes ["on-link"](https://superuser.com/questions/59996/what-does-on-link-mean-on-the-result-of-route-print-command). I have tried creating on-link routes using the `route add` command and omitting the `gateway` entry, but that hasn't worked.

How can I create an on-link route in Windows 7?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You need to put `0.0.0.0` in the `gateway` entry to create an "on-link" route.

For example, enter the following command in `cmd.exe` or bash:

`route add 10.10.10.100 mask 255.255.255.0 0.0.0.0`

Comment: Please describe steps required to do it.

Comment: how do I specify the interface?

Comment: What's the on-link for IPV6?

Answer (score 2):

The answers here are right when it comes to ipv4, but ipv6 information is missing, so for the others like me looking for ipv6 equivalent, the "on-link" bit would be simply `::`. So if you want to add a v6 route to, for example `fe80::edc8:81a:d696:331/128` (single ip6), command would be:

```
route add fe80::edc8:81a:d696:331/128 ::
```

And in case you want to specify the interface, just add `if <number>` to the end of the command. Say, if you want to specify interface 10:

```
route add fe80::edc8:81a:d696:331/128 :: if 10
```

(usually interface 1 should be the loopback device)

Answer (score 1):

You can add an interface using the command

```
route add 10.10.10.100 mask 255.255.255.0 0.0.0.0 IF <26>
```