# Exact trace of outbound packet based on routing table

Tags: packet, routing-table

Say I have a routing table

```
IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.0.1      192.168.0.2     30
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
      192.168.0.0    255.255.255.0         On-link       192.168.0.2    286
      192.168.0.2  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.0.2    286
    192.168.0.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.0.2    286
===========================================================================
```

and I want to send a ping request to `192.168.0.3`.

Newly created a packet with destination `192.168.0.3` (and source 127.0.0.1?) appears on the network. It will hit the rule `192.168.0.0/24` with interface `192.168.0.2`. The packet gets  source changed to `192.168.0.2` (based on [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/60104/1679504)). It didn't hit the first rule, so it cannot use the gateway at the moment, yet somehow the packet leaves.

What are next steps in this case and why?

Answer (score 0):

The packet doesn't start with the source 127.0.0.1, it likely starts with either the source * (aka 0.0.0.0) or 192.168.0.2 which should be the local host's IP.

1. If the IP was something other than 192.168.0.0/24, it would head for the default route (first rule),
2. and to get to the default route target, it would use the route 192.168.0.0/24 via interface 192.168.0.2 (which would then replace * as source if it didn't start that way).
3. This could be further routed, but not to internet, as 192.168.0.0/16 is a reserved address.  Presumably, 192.168.0.1 is a NAT router, and it would translate the local address+port to its own WAN ip and a different (connection unique) source port, and retranslate the reply back.

Since the target 192.168.0.3 matches 192.168.0.0/24, it would go directly to that network, via the same rule 2 above, and there routing would stop and ethernet takes over (presumably).  Ethernet would send an arp request for 192.168.0.3 (assuming it wasn't already in the arp cache) and when it got a reply, send the packet directly to the destination with  192.168.0.2+local mac --> 192.168.0.3+reply mac.

The addresses 127.0.0.0/8 are unroutable and if the source starts with that, the packet will never leave the local machine.  The source IP is in control of the application; it can bind a specific source IP, usually one of the host's interface ip's, but typically the source IP is left unbound by the application and will default to * with some (semi-)random port.

Comment: I think it can't go directly, because when I removed the gateway rule, ping didn't reach the target at first: `ping 192.168.0.3

Pinging 192.168.0.3 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.0.2: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.0.3: bytes=32 time=5ms TTL=64`
GIven that, how come the default route is selected when it's back? There is still `192.168.0.0/24` available - doesn't it apply because it was chosen the last time?